# KDE | Shortcuts to Open Default Applications?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, kde5, defaults

Is it possible to define global keyboard shortcuts to open default applications?

For example, I want to define a shortcut <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to open up the default browser, such that if I ever decide to change my default browser it'll still work, and won't be specific-browser-dependent.

Comment: This is imho one of many great features KDE has to offer - the global shortcuts in system settings. Here's a link to guide howto: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-on-kde-plasma-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can define the shortcut to open `x-www-browser`. The script calls the application configured to run on any desktop environment that runs under X (KDE included). Using this script you can write settings independent from the installed browser. `x-www-browser` can be configured using

```
# update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

or

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

---

I personally use an environment variable `$BROWSER` (`BROWSER=firefox` i.e. in your login scripts). I prefer this solution, since it allows to change the default browser just by changing the variable and works on any system. But I am not sure if on KDE you can create a keyboard shortcut to run `$BROWSER` or any environment variables.